# IAM tag policy with condition to prevent resource creation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

My IAM user has the below two policies attached to it.

I created the below IAM policy that prevents lambda from being created if it does not have the Project tag.

```
 {
        "Version": "2012-10-17",
        "Statement": [
            {
                "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
                "Effect": "Deny",
                "Action": "lambda:*",
                "Resource": "*",
                "Condition": {
                    "Null": {
                        "aws:RequestTag/Project": "true"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
```

I also need to attach/create a new execution role when creating lambda so I added below
Iam policy to my IAM user.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "iam:*",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

I logged into aws console using that IAM user's credentials and tried to create the lambda function without the tag, but it did'nt block the resource creation.I was able to create the lambda function without the required tag but with the following errors.

```
You are not authorized to perform: cloudformation:DescribeStackResources.
You are not authorized to perform: lambda:GetFunctionEventInvokeConfig.
User: arn:aws:iam::****:user/testuser is not authorized to perform: lambda:ListEventSourceMappings on resource: * with an explicit deny (Service: AWSLambda; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDeniedException; Request ID: 199433ed*****)
```

How can I completely block the resource creation?

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/organizations/latest/userguide/orgs_manage_policies_example-scps.html#example-require-tag-on-create

Eventually I want to try aws:RequestTag/{TageKey} for all supported aws resources.

Comment: Shouldn't this be a `Deny` in that policy? `SCP` example you've linked has only `Deny` there.

Comment: Thanks Marcin for pointing the mistake!

Comment: No problem. Is it working now? If, I can make answer for future reference?

Comment: Its still letting me create the lambda function but I get some errors this time.

Answer (score 0):

Not all AWS services/resources support aws:RequestTag as a condition key.
For lambda it is not allowed. Currently the supported condition keys on lambda:CreateFuncion Action are:

- lambda:Layer
- lambda:VpcIds
- lambda:SubnetIds
- lambda:SecurityGroupIds
- lambda:CodeSigningConfigArn

As specified on table "Actions defined by AWS Lambda" on column "Condition keys".
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/list_awslambda.html#awslambda-actions-as-permissions

You can check that link and review any other service and validate if a specific Action support the Condition that you need.
For example, for EC2:RunInstances https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/list_amazonec2.html supported conditions are:

- **aws:RequestTag/${TagKey}**
- aws:TagKeys
- ec2:AvailabilityZone
- ec2:EbsOptimized
- ec2:InstanceMarketType
- ec2:InstanceProfile
- ec2:InstanceType
- ec2:IsLaunchTemplateResource
- ec2:LaunchTemplate
- ec2:MetadataHttpEndpoint
- ec2:MetadataHttpPutResponseHopLimit
- ec2:MetadataHttpTokens
- ec2:PlacementGroup
- ec2:Region
- ec2:RootDeviceType
- ec2:Tenancy

So in that case you can restrict creation on new EC2 instances based on the presence of Tags but for Lambda it is not supported (for now).